# Fetch multple data that have the same id sing php

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

```
Matric No  Name                            Supervisor Name              Section
0924564    Nur Hidayah Mohammad Daud       |Che Siti Fatimah Che Hasan  1
1017951    Nur Akmal Hakeem Zainal Abidin  |Ali                         2
1017164    Qurratu 'Aini Zaini             |PHONE MYINT NAING           3
23         Eshrak                          |Ali                         2
```

This is basically what's in the table. How can I fetch the row of students which have the same supervisor?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to something like this

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  Supervisor Name
        FROM    TableName
        GROUP   BY Supervisor Name
        HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
    ) b ON  a.Supervisor Name= b.Supervisor Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one table then you can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Supervisor Name),Matric No,Name,Section FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Matric_No,
    Name,
    Supervisor_Name,
    Section,
    count(Section) as Total
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Section
Having Total > 1
```